# Angular Material 2: use a different font config for headers?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular-material2

I have an Angular Material 2 app on angular 7.

I have followed the [documentation for typography](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography) and defined the base typography:

```
$sc-typography-config: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
  $display-4: mat-typography-level(112px, 112px, 300),
  $display-3: mat-typography-level(56px, 56px, 400),
  $display-2: mat-typography-level(45px, 48px, 400),
  $display-1: mat-typography-level(34px, 40px, 400),
  $headline: mat-typography-level(24px, 32px, 400),
  $title: mat-typography-level(20px, 32px, 500),
  $subheading-2: mat-typography-level(16px, 28px, 400),
  $subheading-1: mat-typography-level(15px, 24px, 400),
  $body-2: mat-typography-level(14px, 24px, 500),
  $body-1: mat-typography-level(14px, 20px, 400),
  $caption: mat-typography-level(12px, 18px, 400),
  $button: mat-typography-level(14px, 14px, 500),
  $input: mat-typography-level(14px, 1.25, 400)
);
```

And then defined this config in the `mat-core` mixin as described in the docs:

```
@include mat-core($sc-typography-config);
```

Fine.

However, I want to use a different config for all the headers (display, headline, title).  So I make a second config:

```
$brand-typography-config: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'PrecisionSans,"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'
);
```

I can apply this to things like buttons using

```
@include mat-button-typography($brand-typography-config);
```

But how do I override the display-*, headline-*, subheader-*, title etc?

Answer (score 1):

The parameters of `mat-typography-level` :

```
@function mat-typography-level(
    $font-size,
    $line-height: $font-size,
    $font-weight: 400,
    $font-family: null,
    $letter-spacing: null)
```

So I think that you should be able to use it like this :

```
$alternative-font-family: 'PrecisionSans,"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif';
$sc-typography-config: mat-typography-config(
    $font-family: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
    $display-4: mat-typography-level(112px, 112px, 300),
    $display-3: mat-typography-level(56px, 56px, 400),
    $display-2: mat-typography-level(45px, 48px, 400),
    $display-1: mat-typography-level(34px, 40px, 400),
    $headline: mat-typography-level(24px, 32px, 400, $alternative-font-family), // <---
    $title: mat-typography-level(20px, 32px, 500),
    $subheading-2: mat-typography-level(16px, 28px, 400),
    $subheading-1: mat-typography-level(15px, 24px, 400),
    $body-2: mat-typography-level(14px, 24px, 500),
    $body-1: mat-typography-level(14px, 20px, 400),
    $caption: mat-typography-level(12px, 18px, 400),
    $button: mat-typography-level(14px, 14px, 500),
    $input: mat-typography-level(14px, 1.25, 400)
);
```